# Can a monadic rose tree have a MonadFix instance?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, monads, monadfix

Given

```
newtype Tree m a = Tree { runTree :: m (Node m a) }
data Node m a = Node
  { nodeValue :: a
  , nodeChildren :: [Tree m a] 
  }
```

Is there a valid `MonadFix` instance?

My attempt was

```
instance MonadFix m => MonadFix (Tree m) where
  mfix f = Tree $ do
    Node
      <$> mfix (runTree . f . nodeValue) 
      <*> fmap nodeChildren (runTree (mfix f))
```

Yet this doesn't seem to terminate when I actually try and use it. The instance is somewhat inspired by the `MonadFix` instance for lists.

Comment: What would the `Monad (Tree m)` look like to begin with?

Comment: See http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog-0.5.1/docs/Hedgehog-Internal-Tree.html#t:Tree - this is the `Tree` I'm trying to add `MonadFix` to.

Comment: Ok, [I may have something for you](https://gist.github.com/gallais/4c59b949c743c0a85cab55dcb73aaf7c) then. It is based on my understanding of `MonadFix []`: use `fix` on `f` to grab the shape of the top layer, and generate the subtrees by calling `mfix` recursively on the subpositions with a modified `f` that targets each position precisely. I'm pretty confident that it does the right thing for `Tree Identity` however I'm not convinced I'm not forcing some `m` actions too early wrt what I infer is the `Tree m`'s semantics.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll give that a try and see what the behavior is.

Comment: Unfortunately @gallais that doesn't seem quite right. I tried out your file and then ran: `nodeValue <$> runTree (mfix (const (return ()))`, which I believe should just be `()` (using `return` for `Tree` just creates a `Node` with a value and no children). In fact, it actually just blows the stack with a stack overflow exception (how appropriate).

Comment: It indeed doesn't work with `m` equal to `IO` but I tested it with `Identity` or `State Int` and it seems to be working out. I wonder what's special about `IO` (or whether we can find other failing examples).

Comment: @gallais I think this is the fix: https://gist.github.com/ocharles/9b6fb71669de4533373a9c7f1f3ce8f9. You need to `mfix` rather `fix`, and hence `m` must also be `MonadFix`. That at least satisfies my above example in `IO`.

Comment: This type smells a lot like `FreeT []`. Is it? If so, and if the instance you give is valid, under what circumstances can `FreeT f m` have a valid `MonadFix` instance?

Comment: @dfeuer more like CofreeT [], no?

Comment: @ocharles, ah, yes, I mixed sums with products. Please apply my question to the type I should have meant!

Comment: @ocharles since you have the solution, mind posting it as an answer and accepting it?

Comment: @sclv done, thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real solution really comes from [gallais](https://stackoverflow.com/users/727667/gallais) with a small modification. We lifted the core idea out into the `containers` library too, with `MonadFix Tree` instance [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.11.0/docs/src/Data.Tree.html#line-182)

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

module MonadTree where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Fix

newtype Tree m a = Tree { runTree :: m (Node m a) }
  deriving (Functor)

data Node m a = Node
  { nodeValue :: a
  , nodeChildren :: [Tree m a]
  } deriving (Functor)

valueM :: Functor m => Tree m a -> m a
valueM = fmap nodeValue . runTree

childrenM :: Functor m => Tree m a -> m [Tree m a]
childrenM = fmap nodeChildren . runTree

joinTree :: Monad m => m (Tree m a) -> Tree m a
joinTree = Tree . join . fmap runTree

instance Monad m => Applicative (Tree m) where
  pure a = Tree $ pure $ Node a []
  (<*>)  = ap
instance Monad m => Monad (Tree m) where
  return = pure
  m >>= k =
    Tree $ do
      Node x xs <- runTree m
      Node y ys <- runTree (k x)
      pure . Node y $
        fmap (>>= k) xs ++ ys

instance MonadFix m => MonadFix (Tree m) where
  mfix f = Tree $ do
    node <- mfix $ \a -> do
      runTree (f (nodeValue a))
    let value = nodeValue node
    let trees = nodeChildren node
    let children = zipWith (\ k _ -> mfix (joinTree . fmap (!! k) . childrenM . f)) [0..] trees
    return $ Node value children
```